# Django translations not working without language tag and execute on button clcik

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates, django-i18n

I have a block of text that I want translated when the user click a button. I've run the following code:

```
mkdir project/locale
django-admin makemessages -l fr
django-admin compilemessages
```

In my html I have the following:

```
<h5 class="slim">{% trans "This is an example" %}</h5>
```

My translation only works if I do this in my html:

```
{% language 'fr' %}
<h5 class="slim">{% trans "This is an example" %}</h5>
{% endlanguage %}
```

I've tried changing the language in settings.py to 'fr' from 'en' and getting rid of {% language 'fr' %} and {% endlanguage %} but the translation did not work when I did that.

Here is whats in my settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware', # ADDED TO FILE FOR TRANSLATION
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('fr', _('French')),
    ('de', _('German')),
)
```

And here is what's in my .po file:

```
msgid "This is an example"
msgstr "Ceci est une example"
```

Comment: What do you mean `your translation works`? How are your `urls.py` constructed?

Comment: I dont have any urls for language

Comment: If my answer solved your issue, accept it, please!